# EJBCA-ce-6-1-1- JBOS-7-final - Ubuntu 12.04 : ant deploy fail

Tags: ant, jboss, ca, ejbca

I tried to apply steps explained at ejbca website but when I come to "ant deploy" it didn't work

on ubuntu termenal this appears

```
> lama@lama-VirtualBox:~/ejbca_ce_6_1_1$ ant install
Buildfile: /home/lama/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/build.xml

customejbca.message:
     [echo] No custom changes to merge.

appserver.error.message:
     [echo] 'appserver.type' could not be detected or is not configured. Glassfish 2.1.1, Glassfish 3.1, Glassfish 4.0, JBoss 5.1.0.GA, JBoss EAP 5.1, JBoss 6.0, JBoss 7.1.1, JBoss EAP 6.1 and 6.2, WildFly 8, WebLogic 10.3.3, WebSphere 7.0.0.13 can be detected. (Is 'appserver.home' configured?)
     [echo] jndi.properties.file: /home/lama/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.${appserver.type}

fail-unless-appserver-detected:
     [echo] appserver.home: ${env.APPSRV_HOME}
     [echo] appserver.type: ${appserver.type}
     [echo] appserver.subtype: ${appserver.subtype}

BUILD FAILED
/home/lama/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/propertyDefaults.xml:263: 'appserver.type' could not be detected or is not configured. Glassfish 2.1.1, Glassfish 3.1, Glassfish 4.0, JBoss 5.1.0.GA, JBoss EAP 5.1, JBoss 6.0, JBoss 7.1.1, JBoss EAP 6.1 and 6.2, WildFly 8, WebLogic 10.3.3, WebSphere 7.0.0.13 can be detected. (Is 'appserver.home' configured?)

Total time: 2 seconds
lama@lama-VirtualBox:~/ejbca_ce_6_1_1$
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this error ?

Thank you

Comment: did you set appserver.home in conf/ejbca.properties? if you did not, set jboss home directory in conf/ejbca.properties or export APPSRV_HOME=<path-to-jboss-directory>

Answer (score 1):

As hamed pointed out, you don't have ejbca.properties file or the file is missing the appserver.home entry.

Answer (score 1):

From the installation guide of EJBCA:

*Configure EJBCA so it can find the application server (JBoss).*

```
echo "appserver.home=/home/user/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final" >> ejbca_6_0_3/conf/ejbca.properties
```

You need to customize the **user** and maybe your **jboss** und **ejbca** version :). Or maybe as well the whole path if you did it completely different.

[Link to the Docs](http://www.ejbca.org/docs/installation.html)